# Debounce in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, timer

This is my attempt at implementing [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) in Scala without any 3rd party library. How can I improve the code/make it more idiomatic (and any bugs I might have missed)?

```
  import scala.compat.Platform.{currentTime => now}
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.util.control.NonFatal

  /**
   * Return a function f that it can only be invoked iff it is not already running
   * and atleast wait duration has passed since it last stopped running
   * Usage:
   *    def plus1(x: Int) = println(x + 1)
   *    val f = debounce(1.second)(plus1)
   *    f(1)
   *    f(2)
   *    Thread.sleep(2000)
   *    f(3)
   * 
   * @return a function such that it returns Some(original output) if it was invoked 
   *         or else if it failed to run because of above rules, None
   */
  def debounce[A, B](wait: Duration)(f: A => B): A => Option[B] = {
    var (isRunning, lastStopTime) = (false, Long.MinValue)
    (input: A) => {
      if (!isRunning && lastStopTime + wait.toMillis <= now) {
        try {
          isRunning = true
          Some(f(input))
        } catch {
          case NonFatal(e) => throw e
        } finally {
          isRunning = false
          lastStopTime = now
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most noticeable problem is the race condition on the access of `isRunning` within the returned anonymous function. It is possible that two different threads can call the function at the same exact time, so they both see that `isRunning == true` before it is flipped to `false`.

For example:

```
def test(i: Int): Int = { println(i); i }
val db = debounce(1.seconds)(test)
```

When running making many concurrent calls to `db`, it occasionally will leak an extra `Some`, noted by the extra printed number (occurred less than 1ms after the original call).

```
scala> (0 to 10000000).par.map(db)
0
5001723
```

The easiest way to fix this is to synchronize access to `isRunning` (and really, the whole function), which can be done by surrounding the result of the function with `this.synchronized`:

```
def debounce[A, B](wait: Duration)(f: A => B): A => Option[B] = {
  var (isRunning, lastStopTime) = (false, Long.MinValue)

  (input: A) => this.synchronized {
    if (!isRunning && lastStopTime + wait.toMillis <= now) {
      try {
        isRunning = true
        Some(f(input))
      } finally {
        isRunning = false
        lastStopTime = now
      }
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
```

This will have some performance implications, particularly if `f` is slow, since we are locking on it's evaluation. That is, you can end up blocking the calling threads when making multiple concurrent calls while waiting for the first `f` to evaluate.

I also removed the `catch` block, as it was superfluous.

---

I should note there is also a fundamental difference between the way your method behaves, and the linked javascript function. Yours intends to prevent `f` from being evaluated more than once during a specific duration after an evaluation (rate limiting). Underscore's `debounce` method will not evaluate the function at all until one `wait` period after the last call to it has expired. That is, if `wait` was one second and my function `db` was called once every 0.5 seconds repeatedly, the contained function would never be evaluated (with the underscore behavior). The author of that post does not seem to understand that underscore's `debounce` is *not* for rate limiting, but for calling a function after a stream of input has been interrupted for an arbitrary amount of time.

---

For fun, here is a version that uses `AtomicBoolean`, similarly to a `ReentrantLock`. It should be better than synchronize in that it won't block calling threads while `f` is evaluating. It uses `compareAndSet` to first check that `isRunning` is `false`, and then sets it to `true` if it was already `false`, but only if the `wait` hasn't expired. This ensures that it isn't currently running, and it doesn't prematurely re-lock before the time has elapsed.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

def debounce[A, B](wait: Duration)(f: A => B): A => Option[B] = {
    var (isRunning, lastStopTime) = (new AtomicBoolean(false), Long.MinValue)

    (input: A) => {
        val doneWaiting = lastStopTime + wait.toMillis <= now
        if (isRunning.compareAndSet(false, doneWaiting) && doneWaiting) {
            try {
                Some(f(input))
            } finally {
                lastStopTime = now
                isRunning.set(false)
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly to the `ReentrantLock` though, this suffers from contention to check the status of `isRunning`. Which means that if there are many concurrent calls to `compareAndSet`, it will actually delay the call to `set`. This shouldn't really be a problem unless a ridiculous amount of calls are being made, though.

Comment: Thank you for the review. And, yes, I actually prefer this behaviour over underscore's :) Would it be better if we make isRunning an atomic boolean and not put synchronized?

Comment: It's possible, but that opens up the possibility for a different race condition that I've been trying to resolve. The wait period is what complicates it, so I need to think about it more.

Comment: Regarding the performance optimization when f is slow, an improvement could be to do an eager check outsize the sync block and do once more inside e.g. `if (!isRunning) synchornized { if(!isRunning) .... }`

Comment: @wrick Added a version using `AtomicBoolean`, which won't synchronize over `f`.

Comment: Why didn't you use `if(!isRunning.get() && lastStopTime + wait.toMillis <= now) { isRunning.set(true) ...` ?

Comment: That would re-introduce the race condition. `compareAndSet` lets us check and lock it in one step. Otherwise, two callers might make it inside the `if` when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Debouncing a function like that requires mutable state, which is never going to be very idiomatic. To get more idiomatic (and get rid of the mutable state), I'd reconsider the architecture and probably use something like ScalaRX. Debouncing is something that works quite naturally with Streams.

Comment: Can you explain how to debounce with streams?